# Mounting a drive is chaotic with the two NVMe SSD drives

Tags: 18.04, mount, ssd, fstab, nvme

My new computer has two NVMe SSD chips. Both are on the motherboard (no PCIe cards involved). On one of them there's the operating system and the other is for large data storage. For that, I wrote this on `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/nvme1n1p1    /mnt/data    auto    defaults    0    1
```

However, which of them is `nvme0n1p1` and which is `nvme1n1p1`? That's totally random, and potentially changes on every restart of my system.

Because of that `fstab` line, some times the right drive is mounted on `/mnt/data`, and some times the system drive. So to fix this, I have to manually go to `fstab` and change the numbers from 0 to 1 or the opposite, then

```
sudo umount /mnt/data
```

then

```
sudo mount -a
```

And that fixes the problem. But I have to do this every now and then **MANUALLY**. This makes it impossible to associate anything on from the data drive with startup, because I'll never know which of them will be mounted on `/mnt/data`.

What do you think? Where is this problem coming from?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: What are you using to mount them in your /etc/fstab?   UUIDs are used because they are Unique (one of the U's). Change your /dev reference to use the UUID= so it's unique and always the same.  Use `blkid` to get the UUID for each device/partition, and code that in your /etc/fstab

Comment: @guiverc Correct. I'm using the line you see up there as it's. I'll try to get UUIDs. Sounds like a good solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to guiverc for pointing out the solution. It's simply to mount using UUID and not drive path. This is the way to do it:

1. Get the list of your drives:

```
$ lsblk
```

returns:

```
nvme1n1     259:0    0   1,8T  0 disk
└─nvme1n1p1 259:5    0   1,8T  0 part /mnt/data
```

2. Get the UUID of the drive you're interested in:

```
$ sudo blkid | grep -i nvme1n1p1
```

Now change my fstab line from this:

```
/dev/nvme1n1p1    /mnt/data    auto    defaults    0    1
```

to this:

```
UUID=388f4772-1f41-4b13-9c74-9ed56c4bacc5    /mnt/data    auto    defaults    0    1
```

And that does it.

Comment: You can see both mount & UUID with lsblk `lsblk -f`